# organize data acccording to the first letter it starts with, like an English dictionary

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to organize data acccording to the first letter it starts with, like an English dictionary.

**Option A** Store words in a single table.

The field `word_id` is a PK, `name` is unique/index field and `word_code` possibly a primary column or just a regular column but has to be indexed.

Storing all the words in one table is an easy way to start with my project, but I'm not sure whether this table becomes slower as it grows.

Table: `word`

| word_id | word_code | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 112 | pizza |
| 2 | 97 | alien |
| 3 | 111 | orange |
| ... | 99 | candy |
| 10000000 | 99 | cat |

**Option B** Create partitions in `word`.

The partition may provide `INSERT` performance benefit, but not affect the `SELECT` speed. According to a book, when I read/write all the partitions that I've created regularly, I won't have a better read performance regardless of the partition types. Some people say that creating partitions seem pointless when the size of table is small. (No performance benefits and maybe slower than a single table in some situations.)
When would be the right time to create one? Maybe when the size becomes over a million? I'm not even sure it is worth creating the partition in the first place.

**Option C** Create 26 tables from a-z and store each word separately.

At first glance it looks reasonable to organize data for the long term. On the other hand, it forces me to write more server-side code and might be difficult to maintain as well.

Table: `word_starts_with_a`

| word_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | alert |
| ... | art |
| 10000000 | angle |

Table: `word_starts_with_b`

| word_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bus |
| 2 | bear |
| ... | bath |
| 10000000 | bubble |

Which should I use one of those options (or a better way to store the data efficiently) as a parent table referenced by children tables?

The parent table is subject to INSERT and SELECT operations.

Comment: 1) we have no idea what you use the word data for. 2) we have no idea how large you expect the word table to grow Based on these, we cannot really tell you which option is the best for you. What you really should do is to generate sample data large enough for your purposes and **test** all three options and you will **know** the answer for sure!

Comment: @Shadow - Yeah, the OP is missing some critical info; hopefully my Answer will keep them from barking up that 'bad' path (a..z) toward "premature optimization".

Comment: [mre] [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) 
[Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: @Shadow The word data is for a web dictionary service. I don't understand why you don't get it from the examples I've provided above. Other than that, your comment reminded me to think about my issue in a different perspective. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds more like a "lexicon" than a "dictionary".  Would there also be columns for definition, entomology, pronunciation, similar words (thesaurus), etc?  Those would make the table perhaps 10 times as big as first described; my answer probably won't change.

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim I do not understand what the data is used for because you have not described it! There can be dozens of different use cases for word data, particularly if you have a column there like you word_code, which we cannot have any clue as to whay purpose it serves. You have all the background information, but we do not.

Comment: @RickJames Exactly. I should have rephrase the dictionary as the "lexicon"

Comment: @Shadow Fair enough. I should have elaborated more. The basic idea was storing just random words in a table. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database Table is unordered.  `SELECTs` that include an `ORDER BY` clause produce ordered output.

Fetch all words in alphabetical order, *regardless of what order they were inserted*:

```
SELECT name FROM t ORDER BY name;
```

Fetch all words beginning with "B", in arbitrary order:

```
SELECT name FROM t WHERE name LIKE 'B%';
```

Fetch all words beginning with "B", in *alphabetical* order:

```
SELECT name FROM t WHERE name LIKE 'B%' ORDER BY name;
```

With a suitable index each of these will take the same amount of time (very few milliseconds) from a *combined* table of *any* number of rows:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE name = 'aardvark';
SELECT * FROM t WHERE name = 'zebra';
```

Do have an index on `name`.  If `name` is unique throughout the table, then consider making it the `PRIMARY KEY` -- `PRIMARY KEY(name)`.  If there can be duplicates, then `word_id` may be necessary.

A thousand-row table is pretty fast simply because it is not big.  A million-row table may need the suggested index (or PK).  A billion-row table certainly will need it.  How many "names" do you expect to collect?  There are only a few million words in any language; and under 8 billion persons in the world (last I heard!).

That is, do not fear performance as the table grows; instead, look for a suitable index.  A "suitable" index is a function of the query.  So we need to see the important queries in order to advise in more detail.

Rule of Thumb:  If you split a word list into the number of tables as there are letters, the largest table will be about 10% of the total.  For example, about 10% of English words start with `S`.  Note that that is not a lot of improvement over having all the words in a single list -- especially since the index is in a BTree structure that has about 100 child nodes for each node.  That is, a billion rows has a BTree of only 5 levels.  That is, my aardvark/zebra example will touch  5 disk blocks to get each of the two rows.  (Caching may prevent the actual need to hit the disk.)  Without a suitable index, 'zebra' would, as you fear, take seconds or even minutes.

Do *not* split the table into multiple tables, nor into multiple `PARTITIONs`.  At least not until we have found a *real* reason to do so.

Comment: Hey Rick thanks for the comment. Your answer helped me a lot. Actually I was planning to collect some Korean words that I believe at least over a million in the future. English words were just an example for helping out the readers for better understanding.

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim - (re Korean) ~11K tables one per 'character') is quite unreasonable.  Split by 33(?) radicals is not much different than English.  (And I wonder if the "10%" applies there.)  I have not checked to see what the utf8 sorting of Korean chars is like; have you?

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim - and...  1M rows?  Medium-sized; no obvious problems.  Be sure to use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, just in case some 4-byte Chinese characters slip in.

Comment: Yeah the size of data will easily increase up to over 10M for sure. Yeah I've already set the character set as`utf8mb4`. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Btw Rick, I've read the post written by you. http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint It definitely helped me getting a general idea. Thanks man!

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim - `SELECT LENGTH('대한민국');` --> 12 (plus 2-byte length); `SELECT LENGTH('Replblic of Korea');` --> 17 (+2)

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dictionaries_by_number_of_words , Korean has only 1.1M words; will the 10M you mention be things other than "words"?  (Eg, "phrases" or "quotations"?)  (For comparison, that says 0.6M for English.)

Comment: People on the internet prefer to make new words like every minute. Also, Hangul (Korean alphabet) is very flexible? I would say, it makes so easy to create one. eg, new slang, compound words, abbreviations and acronyms etc.

Comment: 11K 'characters' --> 121M 2-char 'words' ?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not following..

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim - backing up.  Apparently my "33" is wrong.  And Google is inconsistent on whether there are 24 or 40 or 50 consonants+vowels, and whether there are 11172 or 3192 or some other number of Hangul characters.  Meanwhile, my list of Unicode characters lists only 565 with `name like '%hangul%'` -- that sounds much too low.

Comment: Thanks for your concern and time. I'm not sure what's the point of querying `like '%hangul%'`? There are 19 consonants, 21 vowels and 27 final consonants in Korean. The essential thing to remember is that Korean is a very flexible language and easy to create many different kinds of new words. That's all I care about and I feel kinda worried. Maybe this link helps you understand Hangul more. (english explanation) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQZm3jl68rY